# How to take Out Id From Event in typeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

HTML:-

```
<ion-checkbox color="dark" checked="false" id="1on" (ionChange)="onTap($event)" ></ion-checkbox>
```

TypeScript:-

```
onTap(e)
  {
    console.log(e);

    console.log(e.checked);
  }
```

i want to get id of the checkbox so how can i get it ?

when i access event i can see elemtRef there inside it there is nativeElement inside there is id ? so how to acess id and print it on console.log cant use ajax in ts file .

Comment: why not send as a parameter? ion-checkbox is a custom component of ionic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Worked :

```
  console.log(e._elementRef.nativeElement.id);
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you have a reference to the DOM element. Try this:

const checkboxId = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('id');